# SyntaxError: /home/fzxa/work/blog2/views/articles/index.jade:7

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Sorry, something went wrong. Probably one of our "genius" programmers made a boo-boo! :P

```
SyntaxError: /home/fzxa/work/blog2/views/articles/index.jade:7
    5| div#articles
    6|   - if(articles.length)
  > 7|     !=partial('article_list', {collection : articles, as : 'article'})
    8|   - else
    9|     #no-results No articles found. Create one
    10|       a(href="/articles/new") here

Unexpected reserved word
    at Object.Function (unknown source)
    at Object.compile (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:161:8)
    at Function.compile (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:65:33)
    at ServerResponse._render (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:414:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:315:17)
    at render (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:184:16)
    at renderPartial (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:204:16)
    at Object.partial (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:409:12)
    at eval at  (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:161:8)
    at Object. (/home/fzxa/work/blog2/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:166:12)
```

Comment: Need a little more info - what's the partial view look like?  I wonder if the use of 'as' as a property name is a bad idea as well :-)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305817/syntax-error-home-fzxa-work-blog2-views-articles-index-jade7

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the article_list partial view. The code is using the word "class" which is reserved. In article_list.jade change

```
- if(lastInCollection)
  - class = 'last'
- else
  - class = ''
div(class="article #{class}")
```

to

```
- if(lastInCollection)
  - cls = 'last'
- else
  - cls = ''
div(class="article #{cls}")
```