# Syntax Error: /home/fzxa/work/blog2/views/articles/index.jade:7

Tags: node.js, pug

I am getting syntax error at line 7 of my Jade template:

```
 5| div#articles
 6|   - if(articles.length)
 7|     !=partial('article_list', {collection : articles, as : 'article'})
 8|   - else
 9|     #no-results No articles found. Create one
10|       a(href="/articles/new") here
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I found this possibly-similar issue on Github.  https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/81

You could try tossing in a line like cly does in that article to see if that fixes it:

```
 5| div#articles
 6|   - if(articles.length)
 7|     !=partial('article_list', {collection : articles, as : 'article'})
  |     #filler
 8|   - else
 9|     #no-results No articles found. Create one
10|       a(href="/articles/new") here
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the article_list partial view. The code is using the word "class" which is reserved. In article_list.jade change

```
- if(lastInCollection)
  - class = 'last'
- else
  - class = ''
div(class="article #{class}")
```

to

```
- if(lastInCollection)
  - cls = 'last'
- else
  - cls = ''
div(class="article #{cls}")
```